# How to use the include function for a variable value

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a string includes another one from b.

```
a = "some variable value"
b = ["foo", "bar"] 
c = a.includes(b)
```

How should I do it?

Comment: So `a` is something like `{"hello": "world", "d": ["foo", "bar"]}`?

Comment: do you mean to ask: check if every word in `b` is contained in the string `a`?

Comment: What do you want to archive here? Does a need to include every word given in b or only some? What should happen if b is empty? ... Many questions. Please edit your question so that every corner case becomes clear ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're asking, so if you want to check if the elements in your array are part of the text in your variable `a`, you will need to iterate over `b` to validate if each element is in the string of `a` like this:

```js
a = "some variable value foo"
b = ["foo", "bar"]
b.forEach(x => {
  console.log(`The text '${x}' is in the text '${a}': ${a.includes(x)}`);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Its suppose to be:

```js
c = b.includes(a)
```

whatever element you are checking to suppose to be an argument and `includes` method calls on Array.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.every` is probably the idiomatic way to do this:

```js
const a = "some variable value"
const b = ["foo", "bar"] 
const c = b.every(s => a.includes(s));
```